# Rpart Variables were specificed with different types from the fit?

Tags: r

I make a classification tree using rpart. The data has 10 columns, all properly labeled. Five of these columns contain information such as the day of the week in the form of "Wed" and the other five contain numeric values.

I can successfully make a tree using Rpart, but when I try to run a test set of the data, or even the training set that made the tree, I get a bunch of warnings saying that the variables containing characters were changed to a factor, and then an error that says those same variables were specified with a different type from the fit.

Anyone know how to fix this?

My relavent code should be

```
library(rpart)
#read data into info
info <- data.frame(info)
set.seed(30198)
train_ind <- sample(1:2000, 1500)
training_data_info <- info[train_ind, ]
test_data_info <- info[-train_ind, ]
training_data_info <- data.frame(training_data_info)
test_data_info <- data.frame(test_data_info)
tree <- rpart(info ~ ., data = training_data_info, method = "class")
info.test.fit <- predict(tree, newdata=test_data_info) #this is where it goes wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use character vectors in an `rpart` fit. You have to code them as factors. The code does this for you, but then you hit the problem that it is entirely possible for the test data to have a different set of `levels` from the training data used to fit the tree.

The error arises from the use of these two lines:

```
training_data_info <- data.frame(training_data_info)
test_data_info <- data.frame(test_data_info)
```

These are redundant, the objects are already data frames. All this achieves is to drop those levels from the whole dataset that are missing in either the training or test datasets. And that is where the error comes from. Try without those two lines and you should be good to go.

Comment: I actually had the error before I added those. I put them in to try to fix it, which it didn't do.

I will remove them again if they are redundant, but they are not the source of the error.

Comment: When you said you cannot use character vectors in rpart fits, it got me thinking. I used as.Factor on each column in the training set that was a character vector before making the tree. This solved the errors for some reason.

Comment: Unless you specifically ask for characters to be retained as characters, it is quite tricky to not have them converted to characters. It does seem that you did present characters to `rpart` and that the levels of the factors was causing the error. Looking at the code you showed, that (warning about characters) wouldn't have happened with the example code - but you'd still get the error because the factors in train and test data could have different levels.

Comment: If you like better with a graphic interface, I would suggest you to use Rattle, It has rpart options and when you read a file it has option to mark what kind of variable you wish.